# Problemas al usar SEC_TO_TIME mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en la cual existen dos campos de hora, Hora_reporte y Hora_llegada.
Quiero promediar la diferencia de tiempo que existe entre ambos campos.

Uso la fórmula que dejo a continuación:

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(timediff(Hora_reporte, hora_llegada))) from reportes;
```

El problema es el siguiente, verificando individualmente la fórmula pasa ésto con el resultado:

```
select timediff(Hora_reporte, hora_llegada) from reportes where no_reporte = '02051010';
```

Resultado del query:
01:27:57.000000

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(timediff(Hora_reporte, hora_llegada)) from reportes where no_reporte = '02051010';
```

Resultado del query:
03:32:37.000000

Como podrán ver la diferencia de tiempo es demasiada, se desfasa completamente por ocupar el SEC_TO_TIME. ¿Cómo podría solucionar ese problema?

Answer (score 1):

SEC_TO_TIME necesita "seconds" como parametro , en lugar de timediff , yo usaria timestampdiff del siguiente modo:

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(timestampdiff(second,hora_llegada,hora_reporte)) from 
reportes where no_reporte = '02051010';
```

timestampdiff usa los argumentos al reves que timediff , resta el segundo menos el primero por eso inverti en el ejemplo las columnas.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Lo intente pero me regresa valor en Null...